# i want to show an image in axes3 which is the resultant of two images Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-guide, digital

I want to implement a gui enviroment in which when the user load two images it then select an arithematic operation to apply on these two images. I am stuck in this place. Just tell me what code I use in "Case" values to apply.

```
function pushbutton3_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton3 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
contents = get(handles.popupmenu1,'String'); 
popupmenu4value = contents{get(handles.popupmenu1,'Value')};
% Hints: contents = cellstr(get(hObject,'String')) returns popupmenu1contents as cell array
%        contents{get(hObject,'Value')} returns selected item from     
popupmenu1
switch popupmenu4value

  case 'Add'
    %function of A

    set(handles.figure1,'CurrentAxes',handles.axes3);
    imshow(img2,[]);
  case 'B'
    %function of B
end
```

Comment: It's hard to answer with such a small part of your code and so little information. Are the images already imported in arrays ? Do they have the same size ? If you have `Img1` and `Img2`, why wouldn't `Img1+Img2` work ? (I guess that if you are using a GUI you have enough experience to know how about the `+` operator)

Answer (score 0):

- you can use uigetdir to get the path and name of the image you wish to load.
- you will then need to perform your arithmetic operation on the loaded images before trying to display the modified image (be careful of pixel overflow if for example you are adding the images together - if you have two pixels at value 256 and add them together the result displayed will be 256 not 512 so you would need to use double then convert back to uint8).

without more information of what you want it isn't really possible to provide more help. if you are having trouble with matlab-guide then i suggest searching youtube for tutorials and going through the matlab guide tutorial. it will be much faster and more beneficial to you if you do this first before asking questions here. [youtube - matlab guide](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=matlab%20guide)